# Electron set fullscreen onclick

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to make app window fullscreen on click but get following error `main.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFullScreen' of undefined`

**main.js**

```
    const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

function toggleFullScreen() {
  mainWindow.setFullScreen(true)
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the full screen when you create the windows object.

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, fullscreen: true});
```

Check here what options you can add when you make a window [Electron BrowserWindow](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#new-browserwindowoptions)

My bad, i forgot you want to make it full on click. In a function use this.

```
var electron = require('electron');
var window = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();
window.setFullScreen(true);
```

Comment: I want to go full screen on click not by default

Comment: Thanks it worked can you point me to some tutorial for learning electron as most of examples I found on web use older version of electron so are not helpful

Comment: Oh sorry, i was in the same problem when i begin, just checking the docs and asking here i learned how to handle some problems.

Answer (score 4):

**Suppose you have a certain button that you want to click for FullScreen to be enabled.** The function bellow does the functionality of changing the screen to full screen. All you have to do is call it on the button click.

```
 const handleFullScreen =()=>{
    remote.getCurrentWindow().setFullScreen(true)
}
```

**Note that remote I'm using remote because this function is triggered in the Renderer that's where my button that maximise the screen is.**

Answer (score 1):

Im gonna post a solution you might be facing with fullscreening:

> When fullscreening taskbar getting in way.

When you fullscreen using `mainWindow.setFullScreen(true)` taskbar will get in way when you are on home (all windows minimized) in windows.

Here is the solution:

```
ipcMain.on("fullscreenon",()=>{
  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'screen-saver');
  mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
})
//The order of the commands is important below
//don't setAlwaysOnTop() before getting out of fullscreen.
ipcMain.on("fullscreenoff",()=>{
  mainWindow.setFullScreen(false);
  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'floating')
})
```

Basically, by default setFullscreen uses the level: "floating".
We need a higher level, "screen-saver" is the highest level I think.